# Limit switch interface symmetric bandwidth on a Cisco SG300 switch

Tags: cisco, bandwidth

I got the job to limit the speed on a cisco 1GBit interface so that the link will have 100MBit symmetric and a burst limit of 1GBit. Its the internet uplink for a customer vlan. I am a bit confused because i read of traffic shaping vs policy map. I think i can issue

```
SW# configure terminal
SW (config)# interface GigabitEthernet 0/2
SW (config-if)# srr-queue bandwidth limit 20
```

because 100MBit symmetric means in both directions thats why i choose 20 percent of 1GBit. But how do i set the burst limit in this case?

**Edit** I found a video where someone used

```
rate-limit output <speed> <normal-burst> <max-burst> conform-action transmit exceed-action drop
```

so i think there are different ways. Can you help me which approach should i use?

Thank you very much

Comment: Shaping and/or policing on a switch is never very precise. Until you get into carrier class hardware (metro-e), it's mostly half-baked. In the cisco case, there are multiple commands necessary to really get anywhere. [ https://gregsowell.com/?p=3690 ] And your configs only act on egress.

Comment: It also depends GREATLY on the precise model of switch and IOS version installed on it. Each combination is a bit different. Also you will have to tinker as telling it to limit to a certain speed/bandwidth limit will usually mean it performs much lower most of the time so you have to work at it until you get the results you want in testing.

Comment: @FrameHowitzer, the SG series does not run IOS.

Comment: Yes, of course you are right. I assumed from the formatting of the configuration example. I guess I didn't see that the model was mentioned in the subject/question. Assuming the command line is that similar, I would guess the experience of needing to do tweaking in policing config will remain the same unless the implementation is totally different.